# MS Excel- Optimising my process

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I'm looking for SO's finest MS Excel savants who could potentially crack a painfully annoying issue I have been facing on a daily basis. To put it briefly; I work with sets of data on MS Excel on a daily basis and I frequently have to use the CTRL+F solution to find the criteria I am looking for so I can subsequently replace it with another value. Take the following example:

I have two spreadsheets open- A and B. In spreadsheet A I will have to CTRL+F the word 'unknown'. This will give a result which will contain the word unknown (of course) among other information which I require i.e. 'ABCCorpeation;Unknown;ID1234'. I then manually CTRL+C the ID value at the end of this string of information and open up spreadsheet B. I again CTRL+F and instead of searching for 'uknown' in spreadsheet B, I paste my copied ID. Spreadsheet B is a very simple spreadsheet which just contains IDs and names, so when I paste this ID it gives me a single result and in the column beside it, I can copy down the name associated with the ID. I then go back to spreadsheet A and replace the word 'unknown' with this copied name. Then I would move on.

I assume you struggled to read through that cripplingly long-winded description of my task, but that is an issue which I have to laboriously tackle every day. To add to my woes; the spreadsheet 'A' I describe is actually dozens of spreadsheets which I look for the word unknown in and replace with an actual name after matching it with its corresponding ID.

So my big question is; is there any way that this could be conceivably simplified using a several nested functions or perhaps by the creation of a macro, because to date I have been struggling to do this or even fathom how to tackle it or what to use. Please Stack Overflow, help this MS Excel goblin ease the pain in his fingers. Any advice would be truly appreciated

Comment: It sounds like you have a "master" (and presumably correct) set of reliable data and then 12 separate spreadsheets that have *delimited* partial data. But the ID is the key.  So why even bother searching for "unknown"?  Just write a macro that fetches your master data based on the IDs in the "unknown" sheets. Excel might not even be best for this; a bash `join` could probably do what you want. Have you attempted anything? If so, can you show your attempt?

Comment: Hi Marc, you are pretty much on the mark with the master spreadsheet assumption. Its actually closer to 50 with delimited partial data. My only issue with a macro is my limited understanding of VBA and how a macro will deal with a scenario where the ID copied from spreadsheet A does not match any of the master spreadsheets IDs. This can happen from time to time and requires a request to be sent for additional information. Will the macro ignore all unmatched records in this case. This is an issue when there's so many spreasdsheets- rework, etc

Comment: Apologies for the confusion Yow, I meant to write 'SOF' as in; Stackoverflow. Hope I put your mind at rest atleast.

Comment: How accurate is your format there?  Is it literally "SomeString;NamePart;IDPart"? Do you get other separators? I mean I might suggest that you break the string "TextToColumns", then filter and paste in some kind of lookup formula as required. But a macro is possible and it does sound like some kind of automation is needed.